# Validator for a single char for user input

Tags: c++, user-input, validation

[image] i need to restrict the user from inputting an integer and string when inputting a char. I have a method for an integer i just need to adapt it for a char. Can anyone help me with this.

```
char getChar()
    {
        char myChar;
        std::cout << "Enter a single char: ";
        while (!(std::cin >> myChar))
        {
            // reset the status of the stream
            std::cin.clear();
            // ignore remaining characters in the stream
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
           // ^^^  This line needs to be changed.
            std::cout << 

           "Enter an *CHAR*: ";
    }
    std::cout << "You entered: " << myChar << std::endl;
    return myChar;
}

char getChar()
{
    char myChar;
    std::cout << "Enter an Char: ";
    while (!(cin >> myChar))
    {
        // reset the status of the stream
        cin.clear();
        // ignore remaining characters in the stream
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<char>::max() << '\n');
        cout << "Enter an *CHAR*: ";
    }
    std::cout << "You entered: " << myChar << std::endl;
    return myChar;
}
```

I have tried this and there are no errors.  But it does not woek.

Comment: I can't think of a way that `cin >> myChar` could ever fail due to illegal conversion (`'0'` is a legal `char` for example). You'll need to check the value of `myChar` after the read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the methid to this:

```
char getChar(string q)
{
char input;
do
{
cout << q.c_str() << endl;
cin >> input;
}
while(!isalpha(input));
return input;
}
```

And in my main i have:

string input = "What is your sex M/F?";
    char sex = getChar(input);
    cout << sex <<"\n";

Doin this,  i am not allowed enter a number wen asked what the sex is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing by "does not work" you mean that even when you enter a longer string or a number it's still accepted. That's because all letters and digits input via the `<<` operator is still a single character.

You have to add another check if you don't want non-alphabetic characters:

```
while (!(std::cin >> myChar) || !std::isalpha(mychar))
```

See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) for an explanation of `std::isalpha`.

Comment: your guess was correct where in the method would i put the extra check ?

Comment: @Pendo826 Change the `while` loop to the one in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately  it didnt work.  I added a print screen to show you the output.